# Speed Algorithms for Turn-Based Games?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am creating a demo text-based rpg project and I am having difficulty finding and/or figuring out a way of using the characters' speed to form an algorithm that determines the order of attack in battle. First, I would like any input or guidance to already established algorithms that would be relevant. Otherwise, I could use help with the algorithm idea I have. The terms and code is below. It still needs a lot of work. Thanks in advance!

--How Am I Determining The Order?

1) I order the speeds of the 6 characters in descending order (highest speed in key value 0) in a LinkedHashMap to maintain order

2) Using the fastest speed as a reference, I multiply that by a factor which gives me a small percentage of that speed that I use to determine the order of the characters. For example, lets say the fastest speed is 50 and the factor is 0.1. This would yield a value of 5 (50*0.1 = 5).

3) Now I recursively subtract the value received from the factor calculations to determine speed order. Lets say that the characters speeds are char1=50, char2=40, char3=38, char4=33, char5=30, char6=25. I start by first adding the fastest character to another LinkedHashMap, then I use my factor to receive a new value, essentially I am doing 50-5 to get 45. I check if the second fastest character (char2) has a speed greater than 45, if so I add char2 to the map else I add the previously added char to the map (char1). I then do my subtraction again, 45-5 to get 40 and do the same check. I continue this until I have added all the characters to the map at least ONCE. I consider this my speed pattern. I only have to repeat this pattern, only modifying it as characters die. Here is the order based on the example I have provided above:

char1 w/50 speed

char1 w/50 speed (again)

char2 w/40 speed

char3 w/38 speed

char4 w/33 speed

char5 w/30 speed

char6 w/25 speed

Now that you see what I am trying to do, I am open to suggestions. Here is how I have programmed this, assume I already have ordered my LinkedHashMap by speeds.

```
    // stores entire speed pattern
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 

    // order un-ordered hashMap "list"
    List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Entry<Integer, Integer>>(sortedMap.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {        
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    // maintaining insertion order with the help of LinkedList
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result.put(i, list.get(i).getValue());
    }

    int count = 0;
    // note: totalChars = 6
    // note: multiplierSpeedPattern = 0.1
    double highestSpeed = result.get(0); // highest speed
    while (Math.round(highestSpeed) > 0 && count < totalChars) {        
       double temp = highestSpeed;
       highestSpeed = (double) (temp - (multiplierSpeedPattern * temp));
       int roundedHighestSpeed = (int) Math.round(highestSpeed);
       Log.i(TAG, "roundedHighestSpeed: " + roundedHighestSpeed);
       Iterator iter = result.entrySet().iterator();
       if (iter.hasNext()) {    
           if (result.get(0) > roundedHighestSpeed && result.get(1) < roundedHighestSpeed) {
               map.put(count, result.get(count));           
               count++;                     
           } else if (result.get(1) > roundedHighestSpeed && result.get(2) < roundedHighestSpeed) {
               map.put(count, result.get(count));
               count++;
           } else if (result.get(2) > roundedHighestSpeed && result.get(3) < roundedHighestSpeed) {
               map.put(count, result.get(count));
               count++;
           } else if (result.get(3) > roundedHighestSpeed && result.get(4) < roundedHighestSpeed) {
               map.put(count, result.get(count));
               count++;
           } else if (result.get(4) > roundedHighestSpeed && result.get(5) < roundedHighestSpeed) {
               map.put(count, result.get(count));
               count++;
           } else if (result.get(5) > roundedHighestSpeed) {
               map.put(count, result.get(count));
               count++;
           } else {
               map.put(count, result.get(count));
               count++;
           }
       }
   }
```

My logic is not correct because I need to somehow also check if I already added a character or not to my map. Any help with this?

Comment: "Now that you see what I am trying to do" - sorry, not even slightly. Before we can help you with code, we'd need a much clearer description of the actual process that's being followed. Your step 2 and 3 are basically incomprehensible. Imagine you are talking to someone who has *no idea what you are talking about* - because you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately I do not have the time to read your question thouroughly. However for this class of problems it often comes at hand to first sort the elements.

However a LinkedHashMap keeps the insertion order but does not sort the elements. Use a TreeMap to sort the order (the class of the instances used as keys must implement Comparable or you'll get a class cast exception at runtime).

This should do most of the trick. For details on algorithms I really recommend the great book "Introduction into Algorithms" (written by Cormen, Leierson, Rivest and Stein). It provides great examples and explanations and a wide variety of algorithms. For your problem look about sorting / sweeping algorithms.